# gradle error while downloading artifacts flutter app

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

is there anyone can help me to fix this error,

**Error:**

```
Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
```

i have updated my gradle version to 6.1.1

my **gradle.wrapper.propreties:**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

my **build.gradle(dependecies):**

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the `.gradle` in `C:Users/{username}/.gradle`. Then open your IDE (Android Studio), Set "Enable for HTTPS" and rebuild your application.

Comment: what do you mean by < set enable for https>